# Excel: How to use an Array to concatenate strings that are next to a criteread section (If function)

Tags: arrays, excel

Good Day Everyone

I have an Excel sheet as bellow in two columns. I know how to use an array if function with sum to add up all values next to a column that has met the criterea as in `{=sum(if(A1:A5="YES",B1:B5)}` but how to go about doing it with strings and concatenate so that they show the result as below

Thanks for Any Help

[The Excel array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDMyi.jpg)

Edit: I know there is a easy VBA solution, but was wondering if there is an excell way since there is an easy solution if it was values and not strings.

Comment: Are we allowed a VBA solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm assuming you don't want the relatively easy VBA solution where you recurse through the initial list and concatenate the answers then you could put the following into B8:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$6=$A8,ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$6)-ROW(Sheet1!$B$1)+1),COLUMNS($B1:B1))),"")`

You'd have to drag it across as it'll put them in separate columns but then you should be able to concatenate them into a single column afterwards.

You have to have **Ctrl** and **Shift** held down when inputting as it's an array formula.

Comment: This does not concatenate it though, I have to drag the formula to the right to get a transpose of the answer. Then Concatenate. Very Very Usefull thought Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- Activate iteration in the options. The maximum number of iterations must be equal to or greater than the number of lines.
- Add `=IF(D1=100;1;D1+1)` to cell D1
- This is the formula in cell E1 for the Stark houses:
  `=IF(D1=1;"";IF(D1-1>COUNTIF(B:B;"Stark");E1;E1&INDEX(A$1:A$100;SMALL(IF(B$1:B$100="Stark";ROW($1:$100));D1-1))))`

(I hope that I got the English names of the functions correctly.)

I missed one information: You must enter the function as an array function.

Thanks go to http://www.excelformeln.de/formeln.html?welcher=155

Comment: For this formula it might be useful not to have any other entries below the raw data. Therefore the results should be in a different column (E in this case). However, I think you can simply replace 100 by the respective number of lines of your raw data.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but isnt adding =IF(D1=100;1;D1+1) to D1 going to cause a Circular furmula?

Comment: If you have iteration actived, that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Was really Strugling to get it right and eventualy got an answer from a stackoverflow question on how to concatenate whole columns.

Sorted the data via B and then used =TRANSPOSE(A4:A6)

Then Used F9 on the function to get this line ={"Mansion1","Mansion 2","House 3"}

Copied and Concatenate and just remove the {

But this was not ideal as the data set I want to use this on is 2500+ lines :(
Manualy did it though :( :( but will try the above answers for future use.