# Merging 2 columns data horizontally?

Tags: excel, merging-data

I have this kind of data (2500 rows)

```
 |   A  |  111  |
 |   A  |  222  |
 |   A  |  333  |
 |   B  |  444  |
 |   B  |  555  |
 |   B  |  666  |
 |   C  |  777  |
 |   C  |  888  |
 |   C  |  999  |
```

I would like it to merge like this, still keeping 2 columns, no separators between the data:

```
 |   A  |  111 222 333 |
 |   B  |  444 555 666 |
 |   C  |  777 888 999 |
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What excel are you using?

Comment: What have you researched, tried, and found to not provide the desired output?

Comment: In my experience you can't do this in formulas alone (without a 3rd party add-in). You could do it with formulas but then have the 111  222  333 in separate cells. Or you could do with with a VBA function. Choose your poison.

Comment: @pnuts I thought that too but in a previous question I tried to do that and even though the entries appeared correct in their separate cells when I tried to concatenate them it caused an error.

Comment: I didn't either! I'll try and dig it out.

Comment: see here: http://superuser.com/questions/922975/how-to-combine-values-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-with-a-comma-separato

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476499/excel-how-to-use-an-array-to-concatenate-strings-that-are-next-to-a-criteread-s) is my answer to this question previously where you have answers in different columns.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832559/vlookup-return-multiple-values-to-a-cell) is my one from earlier today which uses a VBA function to do something similar.